# I need to remove folder in URL

Tags: php

I am new to .htaccess, and I need to remove the folders in the URL path.

For example, this:

```
http://(mysite.com)/member/uploads/../../*.*
```

should be replaced with this:

```
http://(mysite.com)/member/*.*
```

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    /member/(.*) /member/uploads/$1    [L]
    RewriteRule    /member/uploads/(.*) /member/$1    [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you format that properly please